# Problems deploying Azure Data Factory via ARM template in Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I am using the code below to try and deploy an Azure Data Factory via ARM template but I get the error:

```
msrest.exceptions.ValidationError: Parameter 'Deployment.properties' can not be None.
```

Code:

```
from haikunator import Haikunator
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources.models import DeploymentMode

parameters = {
    'factoryName': 'TestADF',
    'dataFactory_location': 'uksouth'
}
parameters = {k: {'value': v} for k, v in parameters.items()}

deployment_properties = {
    'mode': DeploymentMode.incremental,
    'template': template,
    'parameters': parameters
}

deployment_async_operation = self.client.deployments.begin_create_or_update(
    self.resource_group, 'azure-sample',   deployment_properties
)
deployment_async_operation.wait()
```

I am using **azure-mgmt-resource** version: 16.0.0

**EDITED**:
Added the two json files exported as ARM templates:

**Template file:**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "factoryName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": "Data Factory name",
            "defaultValue": "TestADF"
        },
        "dataFactory_location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "uksouth"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "factoryId": "[concat('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/', parameters('factoryName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('factoryName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {},
            "dependsOn": [],
            "location": "[parameters('dataFactory_location')]"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Template Parameter file:**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "factoryName": {
            "value": "TestADF"
        },
        "dataFactory_location": {
            "value": "uksouth"
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Based on @Jim Xu's answer:

```
class Deployer(object):

    def __init__(self):

        client_id = ''
        client_secret = ''
        tenant_id = ''
        
        self.subscription_id = ''
        self.resource_group = ''       
        self.creds = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
        self.client = ResourceManagementClient( self.creds, '')
    
    def deploy(self):
        parameters = {
            'factoryName': 'TestAdfPipeline',
            'dataFactory_location': 'uksouth'
        }
        parameters = {k: {'value': v} for k, v in parameters.items()}
        with open(r'ArmTemplateDeployer\templates\TestAdftemplate.json', 'r') as template_file_fd:
            template = json.load(template_file_fd)
        deployment_properties = {
            'mode': DeploymentMode.incremental,
            'template': template,
            'parameters': parameters
        }
        deployment_async_operation = self.client.deployments.begin_create_or_update(
            self.resource_group, 'azure-sample', {'properties': deployment_properties, 'tags': []})
        deployment_async_operation.wait()
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please provide your template?

Comment: @JimXu I have edited and added the 2 ARM template export json files. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use the method `ResourceManagementClient.deployments.begin_create_or_update()` in package `azure-mgmt-resource` to deploy azure arm template. We need to provide `resource_group_name`, `deployment_name` and object [`Deployment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2020_10_01.models.deployment?view=azure-python). For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2020_10_01.operations.deploymentsoperations?view=azure-python#begin-create-or-update-resource-group-name--deployment-name--parameters----kwargs-)
[image]

So, we need to update code `deployment_async_operation = self.client.deployments.begin_create_or_update(self.resource_group, 'azure-sample',deployment_properties)` as `deployment_async_operation = client.deployments.begin_create_or_update('testdata','azure-sample',{'properties': deployment_properties,'tags': []})`.

For example

```
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources.models import DeploymentMode
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
import json


CLIENT_ID = ''
CLIENT_SECRET = ''
TENANT_ID = ''

creds = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=TENANT_ID,
                               client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)
client = ResourceManagementClient(
    creds, '')

parameters = {
    'factoryName': 'TestADFderg',
    'dataFactory_location': 'uksouth'
}
parameters = {k: {'value': v} for k, v in parameters.items()}
with open('./template.json', 'r') as template_file_fd:
    template = json.load(template_file_fd)
deployment_properties = {
    'mode': DeploymentMode.incremental,
    'template': template,
    'parameters': parameters
}
deployment_async_operation = client.deployments.begin_create_or_update(
    'testdata', 'azure-sample', {'properties': deployment_properties, 'tags': []})
deployment_async_operation.wait()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into this. I ran the code but am getting an error  where the code says "deployment_async_operation =". The error is: azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (InvalidSubscriptionId) The provided subscription identifier 'resourcegroups' is malformed or invalid.

Comment: @ibexy According to the error, your subscription id is wrong.

Comment: I went to Azure->Subscriptions and checked again, the subscriptionId is correct. The code runs ok till the very end when it tries to deploy.

Comment: @ibexy Could you please provide the whole code? let me check it.

Comment: I have edited the main question and added code. Please see where I have "EDIT: Based on @Jim Xu's answer:" Thanks!

Comment: @ibexy Please try to update the code as self.client = ResourceManagementClient( self.creds,self.subscription_id ). Besides, please check if you have assigned Azure RABC role to the service principal you use in code

Comment: Applied the above but still got: "azure.core.polling.base_polling.OperationFailed: Operation failed or canceled". Aplogoies these are all new to  me. I am on the "API Permissions" option of the service principal app.Do you know which specific permissions I  need to grand the app? The app already has "user impersonation" permission under the "Azure Service Management" group

Comment: @ibexy please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-steps. Or you can directly run Azure CLI command `az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp"` to create a spn for test.

Comment: apologies it was my mistake all along. I was using an invalid factory name. Finally went to the deployment logs on the portal and saw the error message. Thanks very much it works now!!!